# Using DataAnnotations with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, data-annotations

In pursuit of finding the best way to have a date displayed on a Razor as just a short date, I have stumbled across Data Annotations, they seem quite nice being able to attach additional meta-data to my various models.

Here's the catch though: I'm using NHibernate configured by Fluent NHibernate, and NHibernate doesn't seem to carry the attributes over to it's generated proxy classes.

Is there some way to force it to copy the attributes, or should I not be using my model classes directly in a view, and instead transform the model someway (T4 template?)

Comment: The attributes should be part of your ViewModel, not the persistence model.

Comment: @Phil, I've figured that since I posted this, but I figured it would be worth getting a few other opinions. I'm looking at using AutoMapper to remove some of the drudgery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to separate classes for **view** and **domain model** (nhibernate). Use [automapper](http://automapper.org/) to translate from one to another.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: dont bother with mapping. build your viewmodel directly by Querying off ISession, e.g Session.Query<Domain>.Select(new ViewModel).      It will save you alot of time & perf. only using Session.Get<DomainObject> to get your full domain objects for mutating them.

Answer (score 2):

Are the NHibernate models you are using partial classes?  If so, you can create a separate metadata class to decorate them with the data annotations.  I recently had a similar problem and got this answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0).  Basically, you create a partial class of the same name as the NHibernate class that was generated.  You then create a metadata class with the same fields as that class, decorate them appropriately, and then apply that metadata class to the partial class you created, so that even if you regenerate classes, your partial class won't, and will keep your DataAnnotations around.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
public partial class Person {

}

public class PersonMetadata {

   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "First Name")]
   public string FirstName;
}
```

Source: [Austin Lamb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558100/austin-lamb) via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915957/using-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-with-entity-framework-4-0/4916085#4916085).

Comment: Not sure whether your answer addresses the original question, but the meta data class could possibly be linked to both the domain and the view model.